# Why are prestashop Cart Rules (Vouchers) not showing in frontend?

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop, cart, prestashop-1.6

I successfully generated a test cart rule and assigned to my user.

I can see it both in backoffice and on the my-account page under 'my vouchers'. So we're sure it's recorderd and assigned.

What happens is that in shopping-cart page, even after loggin in with my user, I can't see any voucher field.

Digging deeper, I can say that the $discounts template var is not populated, or, simply it counts zero. So I took a look to the controller, and saw it assign it via `$order->getCartRules()`. And getCartRules simply reads a db table. And surprise?? The order_cart_rule table is empty. So it doesn't get populated. So what could be the problem here? Ever had same issue someone? It's a strange thing..

Probably the main question is: where/when exaclty do the cart and the rules get created/applied? I can see in FrontController the cart being created, but at that point it seems the cart rules are not setted yet.

By the way, I'm running on latest prestashop 1.6.1.4

Comment: default theme? if you delete user assigment, voucher field still not available? And  to see rules in shopping cart you need `getCartRules` method from Cart class and correspondingly `cart_cart_rule` table, because order still not exists yet

Comment: Not default theme (it's a custom theme made by me), but since the problem is ps_order_cart_rule being empty, I'm not sure if it's really a theme issue :( getCartRules does only a direct sql query on _order_cart_rule, anyway also cart_cart_rule is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$order->getCartRules**

The function `$order->getCartRules()` gives you the list of cart rules *applied to this order* (you can find it in a table `ps_order_cart_rule`).

**Where are all cart rules?**

All cart rules are in the table `ps_cart_rule`.

If you have marked a cart rule as `Highlight` - you can see this:

[image: Vouchers field with a hightlighted cart rule.]

If you have added any cart rule to your shop - you can see this:

[image: Vouchers field.]

If you can't see `Vouchers` field - either you don't have any cart rules or your `theme` installed isn't supporting it.

Comment: Yes I know, but as I already wrote above, the problem is that in frontend after loggin in: 1. I can see my cart rule assigned on my account pages but 2. I can't see the vouchers field on the shopping cart page and 3. smarty is not writing that field because the $discounts variable is empty, or, in other words, $order->getCartRules() doesn't find anything in _order_cart_rule because it's empty.

Comment: @Stratboy As I've wrote you are looking in a wrong place. The function `$order->getCartRules()` gives you the list of cart rules applied to the order: I mean only when a customer has bought something and an order was generated - you can find it in the table `ps_order_cart_rule`. 
Apparently you have errors in your custom theme. You need to compare your theme .tpl and javascript to the default theme. And check `'voucherAllowed' => CartRule::isFeatureActive()` in `controllers/front/ParentOrderController.php`.

Comment: you're right. Thank you, solved. $discount is taken into account on the product-line/list, and it's not related to the vouchers input field itself.

Answer (score 0):

is a late answer but i noticed that if you enable paypal it has in paypal.js a line that remove not only the voucher area but also the trashcan to delete a product:

see pic: **https://i.gyazo.com/403a9004aaa745a2817f11884d52346b.png**

```
/* 1.5 One page checkout*/
var qty = $('.qty-field.cart_quantity_input').val();
$('.qty-field.cart_quantity_input').after(qty);
$('.qty-field.cart_quantity_input, .cart_total_bar, .cart_quantity_delete, #cart_voucher *').remove();
```

by renaming the cart_voucher to cart_voucher_2 (if you not use express checkout) and cart_quantity_delete to cart_quantity_delete_2 you will return to have your things right :)